# Extra argument in Call for Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

All I am trying to get multiple objects out of a parse database.

Here is some of my code :

So this does the query :

```
var MainPicture = PFQuery(className: "Staff")
    MainPicture.whereKey("Position", equalTo: "Sales Manager")
    MainPicture.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if(error == nil){

            self.getMainImageData(objects as [PFObject])

        }
        else{
            println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
        }
```

Then I want to get a few rows out of the query :

```
func getMainImageData(objects: [PFObject]) {

        for object in objects {
            let MainPic = object["StaffPic"] as PFFile
            let MainData = object["FirstName","SecondName","Position"] as PFFile
```

MainPic let works, but when I try and do multiple ones like MainData , I get an error : "Extra argument in call" .. I thought this would have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you cannot subscript `PFObject` with multiple items. It is like calling

```
dictionary["key1", "key2"]
```

That will also result in too many arguments.

It is confusing that your variables are Capitalized. They look like class names.